# Поиск числа вхождений повторяющихся символов в строку

Tags: java

Например есть строка `String doc = "oneTwoThreeFourOneTwo"`. Нужно найти число всех повторяющихся символов и создать из него мапу, вроде `Map<Integer, String> count = new HashMap<>();` Мапа должна иметь в конечном результате следующие значения:

```
{one = 2, two = 2, three = 1, four = 1 };
```

С помощью вот такого вот регулярного выражения нашел все соответствия и занес их в мапу:

```
   Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.+)\\1+").matcher(text);

    Map<String, Integer> count= new HashMap<>();
    int count = 0;

    while (m.find()) 
        count.put(m.group(), 0);
```

Но как посчитать само количество? Так же был бы благодарен, если кто-то подсказал бы алььтернативное решение без регулярных выражений.

Comment: Посмотрите, например, [вот тут.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string)

Comment: Пройти по всей строке и увеличить значение в map, где ключом будет код текущего символа.

Comment: А вы не могли бы поточнее сформулировать вашу задачу, т.к. звучит она как "число всех повторяющихся символов", но судя по приведенным примерам вы ищете повторения не для каждого отдельно взятого символа, а для некоторых лексем, причем абсолютно не очевиден алгоритм отбора таких вот лексем (у вас в примере судя по всему - это отбор новых слов, которые написаны в стиле CamelCase, но могут ли быть между ними запятые, точки, пробелы или вообще левые символы и как тогда решать для чего искать повторения?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Character ch : text.toCharArray()) {
   if (map.contains(ch)) {
     Integer total = map.get(ch);
     map.put(ch, total + 1);
   } else {
     map.put(ch, 1);
   }
}
```

P.S.: код не тестировал, но общая суть должна быть понятна.